# Enable ingress-nginx Prometheus monitoring without Helm

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, ingress

A few weeks ago, I installed `ingress-nginx` in my Kubernetes cluster. Now, I realize that was a mistake because that did not come with Prometheus monitoring enabled automatically, and even worse, it doesn't use Helm. So now my `ingress-nginx-controller` is all set up and working, but I am unable to change settings using Helm to create the `ServiceMonitor` and scrape metrics from it.

I've been searching everywhere I possibly can for this and I can't find any documentation on how to get Prometheus to monitor `ingress-nginx` without using Helm. I understand I need to make a `ServiceMonitor` resource, but I can't figure out how to make one specifically for `ingress-nginx` because every solution I find online pretty much boils down to: "oh just use Helm bro".

I attempted to create my own `ServiceMonitor` resource like so:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
    release: kube-prometheus-stack
  name: ingress-nginx-metrics
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  endpoints:
    - interval: 30s
      port: prometheus
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - ingress-nginx
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-nginx-controller
```

It doesn't work, but I have no clue if this is correct or not because again, absolutely no examples online. It seems like everyone is just expected to use Helm to do all the work for you. Does my `ServiceMonitor` need to be in the `kube-prometheus-stack` namespace, the namespace of the service being monitored, or does it not matter?

- My `ingress-nginx-controller` deployment is in the `ingress-nginx` namespace.
- `kube-prometheus-stack` is installed in the `kube-prometheus-stack` namespace.

Can someone point me in the right direction for getting Prometheus to discover the ingress controller without Helm?

Edit: I moved it to the kube-prometheus-stack namespace, and now Prometheus discovers the service monitor, but it shows 0/8 active targets and I still don't see any nginx stats. Do I need to specify the `/metrics` path in the endpoint? I've tried with and without and it doesn't seem to change anything.

Edit: I created a `ClusterIP` service pointing to the `prometheus` port on my `ingress-nginx-controller` and I am able to port forward that and see the `/metrics` route which shows the Prometheus logs. Pointing my `ServiceMonitor` directly at this new `ClusterIP` service doesn't seem to be doing anything either.

Do I need to point the `ServiceMonitor` directly at the `ingress-nginx-controller` deployment? Or does it need to point at a service? I've tried both and didn't see any other results. I can still see `ingress-nginx` in the Prometheus Service Discovery screen, but 0/8 active targets.

Edit:
Here's what I have in my resources now:

NGINX Controller (relevant items only):

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx-controller
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/port: '10254'
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: '10254'
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
          protocol: TCP
        - name: webhook
          containerPort: 8443
          protocol: TCP
        - name: prometheus
          containerPort: 10254
          protocol: TCP
```

NGINX metrics service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-metrics
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx-metrics
spec:
  ports:
    - name: prometheus
      protocol: TCP
      port: 10254
      targetPort: prometheus
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx-controller
  type: ClusterIP
```

NGINX Service Monitor:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-metrics
  namespace: kube-prometheus-stack
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx-metrics
    release: kube-prometheus-stack
spec:
  endpoints:
    - interval: 30s
      path: /metrics
      port: prometheus
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - ingress-nginx
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-nginx-metrics
```

I cannot port-forward to the metrics service I created, the connection times out.

This is what I'm seeing in Prometheus:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ServiceMonitor seems to be correct with the exception that you have defined no path under spec.endpoints.

You also need to define the port named `prometheus` under the ingress-nginx service or deployment.

ServiceMonitors can be debugged this way:-

1. **Check if the ServiceMonitor created is being read by the Prometheus**:-
   Look at the /targets URL. (There should be a target in 0/0
   state at least and use the old Prometheus UI) If not, that means the ServiceMonitor itself is not being picked up by Prometheus.I suggest looking into the following configuration in
   your kube-prometheus-stack configuration.

   ```
       serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false  # is true by default
       serviceMonitorSelector: {} #labels which help Prom identify which servicemonitors to pick up
       serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {} # If this is empty then all servicemonitors in any namespace will be picked up.
   ```

   The default ServiceMonitor has the Helm metadata attached to it
   which is used by the Prometheus Operator to filter/choose the
   ServiceMonitors to monitor. Setting
   `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues:false` will ignore any such
   selection.
2. **If the ServiceMonitor is visible in targets but there are no targets.**:-
   In this case the issue lies between the ServiceMonitor and
   the pods it is trying to scrape.Check if the ports you mentioned are
   accessible and the pods fulfill the selectors mentioned (all `selectors.matchLabels` must match).

My advice would be to start another dummy ServiceMonitor by following [this](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring-prometheus-operator-part3/) and then modifying the ServiceMonitor one step at a time till it starts monitoring the pods

Edit:-

Moving all servicemonitors to the kube-prometheus-stack namespace is not a good practice. Multiple Helm charts generate their own ServiceMonitor objects which are applied in their own namespace.Enabling the prometheus operator to monitor all namespaces for servicemonitors is a better choice.

For nginx side (ports and label would vary based on your implementations, update the same in the yaml below.):-

1. Add the port in the nginx deployment

   ```yaml
    - containerPort: 10254
      name: prometheus
      protocol: TCP
   ```
2. Create a service to map to the monitoring port.

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     labels: [] # labels of your choice
     name: {} # correct name
   spec:
     clusterIP: ""
     ports:
       - name: prometheus
         port: 9913
         targetPort: prometheus
     selector: <all labels in your pods should match>
     type: ClusterIP
   ```
3. Create the ServiceMonitor

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
   kind: ServiceMonitor
   metadata:
       annotations: [] # as required.
       name: ingress-nginx-monitoring
   spec:
     endpoints:
     - interval: 30s
       path: /metrics
       port: prometheus
     namespaceSelector:
       matchNames:
       - <namespace where nginx is deployed>
     selector:
       matchLabels: [] # all labels in the given in the service above should match.
   ```

Comment: I do see the ServiceMonitor being discovered within the Prometheus UI, but I see 0/8 active targets. I do have a port named `prometheus` going to `9113` on the `ingress-nginx-controller`. I'm not sure if that's the right port or if `ingress-nginx` even has the metrics exposed to begin with.

Comment: I've done some more digging, check my edits.

Comment: If I move the `ServiceMonitor` out of the `kube-prometheus-stack` namespace, I can no longer see it in the Prometheus UI. I'd rather keep all my resources in a namespace if possible anyway.

Comment: That should be okay. The rest of the steps would remain the same.

Comment: I don't see the `ServiceMonitor` showing up again in Prometheus when I move it back to the `kube-prometheus-stack` namespace, it's totally gone again. I created a `ClusterIP` service to expose the prometheus port on the controller deployment but that doesn't seem to be finding it either, and I tested that it works by port-fowarding the service and I can confirm that I do see the metrics displayed at `/metrics`.

Comment: What changes did you make to the ServiceMonitor? If the service works correctly and you can see the metrics, then the problem lies in the service monitor. Can you confirm if the matchLabels are correct? They should be equal to the labels present in the Service.

Comment: Okay, so connecting via the service WAS working a short while ago, now port-forwarding to it is just timing out after changing the namespace back. I can port-forward directly to the controller deployment on port 10254 though and that does work. My labels all look correct to me.

Comment: Can you share the results of ‘kubectl get ep’?

Comment: My bad, I've got the service working now, but I'm just back to where I was before. I can see the monitor in Prometheus but 0/8 active targets still.

Comment: If the serviceMonitor is the same as in the question and the matchLabels are all equal to the service and the matchNames has the name space then you can try adding the path: /metrics under the port. If that does not work you can create a new serviceMonitor from the template i provided. Or paste the one you are using along with prometheus screenshot.

Comment: I edited my post with more details

Comment: Both the configs work on my end. Only thing I had to change was the selectors in the Service. Can you get the output of ‘kubectl get ep’ also can you check what it says under the /target UI? It is even monitoring the nginx pods?

Comment: That command gives me one endpoint with the name `kubernetes`, and an IP with port 443. In the /target UI, nginx is not in the list.

Comment: kubectl get ep -n ingress-nginx should give you the name of the service along with Endpoint attached to it. Under the /targets UI the ingress-nginx-metrics should have 0/8. Under that you should see URL and other details related to scraping

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize I needed to specify the namespace with the command. When using the correct namespace, I do see the `ingress-nginx-metrics` service, but it has no IP assigned to it. I only see the 0/8 targets on the /service-discovery page. nginx doesn't show at all on /targets.

Comment: Yes, If you mean under the endpoint column, that means your service in not connected to any pods. Check if the selector field is correct. Selectors should match the labels on the pods.

Comment: I checked it over and over again, It's definitely right. I copied that YAML in my post edit directly from the dashboard. The metrics service has the `app: ingress-nginx-controller` selector, and the nginx controller deployment and service both have the label `app: ingress-nginx-controller`.

Comment: ‘’’app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
 app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx’’’
Try adding these three to the service.selector

Comment: I figured it out actually. I only had the label set on the Deployment, not on the Pod template. It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

The service monitor seems right, only thing is that the service monitor should be in the namespace of the Prometheus stack.

Try the below service monitor:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
    release: kube-prometheus-stack
  name: ingress-nginx-metrics
  namespace: kube-prometheus-stack
spec:
  endpoints:
    - interval: 30s
      port: prometheus
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - ingress-nginx
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-nginx
```

Also when you do, try port-forwarding the Prometheus

```
 kubectl port-forward svc/<SERVICE_NAME_OF_PROMETHEUS> -n kube-prometheus-stack 9090:9090
```

and check in `Targets` and `Service Discovery` options in Prometheus.
[image]
You can see the service monitor in `Service Discovery` and exposed metrics in `Targets`.

Comment: Okay so I moved it to the `kube-prometheus-stack` namespace, and now Prometheus discovers the service monitor, but it shows 0/8 active targets and I still don't see any nginx stats. Do I need to specify the `/metrics` path in the endpoint? I've tried with and without and it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I've done some more digging, check my edits.